# Programmatically configure Jetty's logger

Tags: logging, jetty

How do I programmatically configure Jetty's logger? I'm using Jetty in a standalone application and want to change the log level of some of Jetty's internally generated warnings. Ideally I could do this programmatically (ie, in code) without having to specify an XML file.

I'm using Jetty 6.1.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty uses [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), so you can use any logging framework or slf4j implementation you want .

Jetty comes with the Simple slf4j implementation, which logs INFO levels or above. So, you either change the bundled slf4j jars to an implementation with the log levels you want, or use a bridge to another framework with the levels you want, or provide a custom log class you can set via, for example,

```
System.setProperty("org.mortbay.log.class", "com.example.JettyLog");
```

More information [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging).

Comment: for just setting the log level one can also use System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.DEBUG","true");
test on jetty-7

Comment: For anyone now using Jetty 9, that property has been depreciated - set `org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL` to `DEBUG` instead.

Comment: No version of Jetty has ever used `Slf4j` as the technique for logging.  The closest concept in Jetty 9, is an optional `Slf4jLog` implementation of the Jetty `Logger` that allows Jetty to emit its own logging events to `slf4j-api` (from there all logging events are managed by whatever slf4j implementation you choose)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get hold of the request logs only the solution is over at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html

```
NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("/var/logs/jetty/jetty-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
requestLog.setAppend(true);
requestLog.setExtended(true);
requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");

server.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```