# Programmatically configure Jetty Logger, using a Logger with constructor dependencies

Tags: logging, jetty

Similarly to [Programmatically configure Jetty's logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523595/programmatically-configure-jettys-logger), I'm using Jetty as a standalone application and would like to configure the logger using code rather than configuration files.

I know I can provide a custom log class by setting a property, e.g.: `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class", "com.example.JettyLog");`

However, the log class I want to use requires a constructor dependency (the log file name) and it would be much simpler if there was a way to provide an already constructed implementation to Jetty. E.g.:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger logger = new MyCustomLogger( logFile );
// and then somehow provide the logger instance to Jetty
```

Does anyone know if that's possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.mortbay.log.Logger` is an old Jetty 6 (or earlier) class.

The logging infrastructure on Jetty 6 is not capable of doing what you want to do.

Notes:

- Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2010.
- Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 were EOL in 2014.
- Only Jetty 9 is current, stable, and recommended for production use on the open internet.

If you want to make a custom logger for Jetty, then it is possible on Jetty 9.  But even there, its often easier to just hook into the [`Slf4jLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Slf4jLog.html) layers and create all sorts of logging infrastructure.

See also the [Jetty 9 Logging Documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html) for more examples.

How to do this in code.

- `MyCustomLogger` needs to implements [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger`]
- Initialize your `MyCustomerLogger` and configure it
- Set it as the Logger implementation using [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new MyCustomLogger( logFile ));`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.html#setLog(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Logger))

Note: Be aware that Logging is initialized extremely early in the JVM.  Your initialization should also occur as early as possible, otherwise you will not be able to replace the Logger implementation correctly.

This early initialization of logging is common with logging infrastructure, and that's why all (and I mean all) logging libraries have on-first-load initialization that is configured in a pull technique (not in the push technique you are wanting to use).  Every logging library out there will take its configuration from the logging configuration and infrastructure itself (via xml, properties files, json, INIs, system properties, etc), including things like the filename.

Comment: Do you have an example of using a pre-constructed Logger instance with Jetty 9? I can't find anything in that documentation that uses it.

Comment: `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Log.setLog` should be `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog` in the answer above.